# trying to make a diamond but cant understand how to finish it?

Tags: java

Hey guy so iv been trying to do same exercises on my own lately, and i thought making a diamond out of astricks would be cool , but i got stuck on the last part. This is what im getting and cant figure out how to flip the triangle, or make a complete diamond

```
   *
  ***
 *****

public static String drawDiamond(int n) {
    String results = "";
    int cols = 1;
    int spaces = n / 2;
    while (cols <= n) {
        results += drawChars(" ", spaces) + drawChars("*", cols) + "\n";
        /*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
while(cols>=n){
 results += drawChars(" ", spaces) + drawChars("*", cols)+"\n";<--- this was just test code.

 cols-=2;
spaces++;
}
         */--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        cols += 2;
        spaces--;
    }

    return results;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to draw diamond with asterisks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20129773/how-to-draw-diamond-with-asterisks)

Comment: And also http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0080__Statement-Control/PrintoutaDiamond.htm

Answer (score 0):

Just extending your logic and assuming your n=5, after the 3rd iteration your `cols` value will become 7 and hence coming out of loop.  So when `cols` reached `n` value, you should reverse the process by increment the `spaces` and decrement `cols`.

Make sure you use some other variable for loop condition, otherwise you go for infinite loop